# I have a problem statement which needs to implement some data structure which in turn implements two functions

Tags: java, data-structures

A security is mapped to an Asset category. Over a period of time , security can move to another category.Below is table for eg

```
Security   Asset_category     Start_date   End_date
-----------------------------------------------------
aalp       US_LARGE_CAP       1/1/2015     2/17/2015
aalp       US_LARGE_GROWTH    2/18/2015    3/16/2015
```

I have to implement two functions

```
fetchAssetCategory(String security , Date inputDate)
```

This will return Asset category name which was present for security at that point of time

```
validateSecurity(String security , String assetCat , Date inputDate)
```

will validate the security at that point of time.

Sample input

```
fetchAssetCategory("aalp", "1/20/2015") : return : US_LARGE_CAP
validateSecurity("aalp", "US_LARGE_GROWTH", 2/17/2015) : return false
```

Have to use data structure and mention time and space complexity

I have tried with Hashmap , but got stuck in middle

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public String fetchAssetCategory(String security, Date inputDate) throws ParseException {
    // Approach-1
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    /*
     * String date = sdf.format(inputDate); System.out.println(date);
     */

    ArrayList<Date> startDates = new ArrayList<>();
    startDates.add(sdf.parse("01/01/2015"));
    startDates.add(sdf.parse("02/18/2015"));
    startDates.add(sdf.parse("08/18/2015"));
    startDates.add(sdf.parse("03/17/2015"));
    startDates.add(sdf.parse("05/18/2015"));

    ArrayList<Date> endDates = new ArrayList<>();
    endDates.add(sdf.parse("02/17/2015"));
    endDates.add(sdf.parse("03/16/2015"));
    endDates.add(sdf.parse("12/15/2015"));
    endDates.add(sdf.parse("05/17/2015"));
    endDates.add(sdf.parse("08/17/2015"));

    ArrayList<Security> addRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    Security s1 = new Security("AAPL", "US LARGE CAP VALUE", startDates.get(0), endDates.get(0));
    Security s2 = new Security("AAPL", "US LARGE CAP GROWTH", startDates.get(1), endDates.get(1));
    Security s3 = new Security("AAPL", "US MID CAP VALUE", startDates.get(2), endDates.get(2));
    Security s4 = new Security("AAPL", "US LARGE CAP VALUE", startDates.get(3), endDates.get(3));
    Security s5 = new Security("AAPL", "US MID CAP GROWTH", startDates.get(4), endDates.get(4));
    addRecords.add(s1);
    addRecords.add(s2);
    addRecords.add(s3);
    addRecords.add(s4);
    addRecords.add(s5);

    for (int i = 0; i < addRecords.size(); i++) {
        if (security.equalsIgnoreCase(addRecords.get(i).getSecurity())
                && (inputDate.before(addRecords.get(i).getEndDate())
                        && inputDate.after(addRecords.get(i).getStartDate()))) {
            return (addRecords.get(i).getAssetCategory());
        }
    }

    return "";
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SecurityAssest sa = new SecurityAssest();
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        java.util.Date yourDate = sdf.parse("01/20/2015");
        sa.fetchAssetCategory("AAPL", yourDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you have so far, and indicate where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: I have  understood the problem statement , but unable to think of any data structure(like Hashmap , List or anything else) that will best fit in for this situation.

Comment: can you post a bunch of sample input in a proper format and also sample output. That will help us get more clarity.

Comment: Posted the code above which I have tried out , just wanted to confirm , is the approach correct ?
Also need to know if there is any way where I can compare the dates without parsing them , in their original format 
For eg : Can i compare (01/20/2015).before(01/21/2015)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve this by ordering the list of categories so we can execute a binary search to find the dates. The assumptions here are that there are no overlapping dates for categories for the same security.

To do this we are going to create a comparator that will match any asset categories that have an intersection.

```java
public class IntersectComparator implements Comparator<AssetCategory> {
    public int compare(AssetCategory l, AssetCategory r) {
        if (l.getEnd().isBefore(r.getStart())) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (r.getEnd().isBefore(l.getStart())) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This allows us to both calculate the insert position and to execute a binary search.

```java
public class AssetCategories {
    private final static Comparator<AssetCategory> COMPARATOR = new IntersectComparator();

    private Map<String, List<AssetCategory>> assets = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(AssetCategory assetCategory) {
        List<AssetCategory> categories = assets.computeIfAbsent(assetCategory.getAsset(), k -> new ArrayList<>());
        int insert = Collections.binarySearch(categories, assetCategory, COMPARATOR);
        if (insert >= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Asset category dates intersect with existing asset category");
        }
        categories.add(-insert - 1, assetCategory);
    }

    public AssetCategory fetchAssetCategory(String asset, LocalDate date) {
        List<AssetCategory> categories = assets.get(asset);
        if (categories == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(categories,
                new AssetCategory(asset, "SEARCH", date, date),
                COMPARATOR);

        return index < 0 ? null : categories.get(index);
    }

    public boolean validateAssetCategory(String asset, String category, LocalDate date) {
        AssetCategory assetCategory = fetchAssetCategory(asset, date);
        return assetCategory != null && assetCategory.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(category);
    }
}
```

And you would use it as follows:

```java
        AssetCategories categories = new AssetCategories();
        categories.add(new AssetCategory("AAPL", "US LARGE CAP VALUE", LocalDate.parse("2015-01-01"), LocalDate.parse("2015-02-17")));
        categories.add(new AssetCategory("AAPL", "US LARGE CAP GROWTH", LocalDate.parse("2015-02-18"), LocalDate.parse("2015-03-16")));
        categories.add(new AssetCategory("AAPL", "US MID CAP VALUE", LocalDate.parse("2015-08-18"), LocalDate.parse("2015-12-15")));
        categories.add(new AssetCategory("AAPL", "US LARGE CAP VALUE", LocalDate.parse("2015-03-17"), LocalDate.parse("2015-05-17")));
        categories.add(new AssetCategory("AAPL", "US MID CAP GROWTH", LocalDate.parse("2015-05-18"), LocalDate.parse("2015-08-17")));

        AssetCategory assetCategory = categories.fetchAssetCategory("AAPL", LocalDate.parse("2015-12-14"));
        boolean valid = categories.validateAssetCategory("AAPL", "US MID CAP VALUE", LocalDate.parse("2015-12-15"));
```

This looks like coursework though, so your lecturer may be looking for you to use a map of trees as a data structure.

Comment: That worked very well . Even I have got some more approaches but they were using Java 7 . Thanks Marc :)